# Message is not shown after exception is thrown in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a signature component where users can sign. This component is used as a WebView in iOS application. 
When user puts his signature, I want to notify iOS client that signature is there.

For the sake of purpose I have following directive (`Modules.registerDirective()` is a helper function to create directives)

```
Modules.registerDirective('signatureClientNotifier', ($window:ng.IWindowService) => {
    return {
        scope: {
            isSignatureValid: '@',
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('isSignatureValid', function (value) {
                if (value === 'true') {
                    try {
                        $window['webkit'].messageHandlers.signatureIsReady.postMessage({'platform': 'iOs'});
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Here is how I use this directive in my view

```
<span class="success" ng-show="signatureController.isSignatureValid" 
                      signature-client-notifier 
                      is-signature-valid="{{signatureController.isSignatureValid}}">Success</span>
```

So far so good, and in fact this works and iOS client gets notified about success. In addition to this, I want to show `Success` message inside view.

The problem is that in normal Web application `$window['webkit']` is undefined, so that exception is thrown (therefore `try...catch`). Although I catch exception, but the `Success` message is not show after exception inside my `span`. If I remove the directive from `span` everything works as expected.

Update: Looks like the reason is not actually an exception, but something is messing up with scopes. If I remove `scope` from directive at all, it behaves properly.

Any help is appreciated either to find a reason, or perhaps better solution for the problem :)

Comment: the text `Success` disappears from span or span is not displayed or span is not in the dom...?

Comment: @smnbbrv The text is not displayed from the very beginning, but span is in the DOM. When `isSignatureValid` is message should appear inside the span.